# Content exceeds the width of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been developing an application in ionic v1, but today appeared an error, which I honestly could not find a solution.

This consists, that in certain versions of android on certain devices, the content of the profile view, both as students and teachers, is not kept within a margin that should be.

#### Code

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" align-title="center">
    <a href="#/menuprof" class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></a>
    <p class="title">Perfil Docente</p>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-view>    
    <ion-content has-header="true">

            <div class="list logo-perfil">            
                <div id="res" ng-click="obtenerFoto()">
                    <img ng-src="{{data.ImageURI}}" id="myImage" class="image-size" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="list row">

                <div class="col">
                    <div class="list-borderless">
                        <p class="item">Identificacion</p>
                        <p class="item">Nombres</p>
                        <p class="item">Apellidos</p>
                        <p class="item">Rol</p>
                        <p class="item">Facultad</p>
                        <p class="item">Programa</p>
                        <p class="item">Periodo</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <div class="list-borderless texto-izquierda">
                        <h3 class="item"><strong>{{Cedula}}</strong></h3>
                        <h3 class="item"><strong>{{Nombre}}</strong></h3>
                        <h3 class="item"><strong>{{Apellido}}</strong></h3>
                        <h3 class="item"><strong>{{Rol}}</strong></h3>
                        <h3 class="item"><strong>{{Facultad}}</strong></h3>
                        <h3 class="item"><strong>{{Programa}}</strong></h3>
                        <h3 class="item"><strong>{{Periodo}}</strong></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

    </ion-content>    
</ion-view>
```

#### JS

```
angular.module('perfilEstudiante', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'historialApp'])
       .controller('mostrarPerfilEstu', mostrarPerfilEstu)
       .factory('obtenerPerfilEstu', obtenerPerfilEstu);

mostrarPerfilEstu.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerPerfilEstu', '$cordovaCamera', '$cordovaFile', 'salirApp'];

function mostrarPerfilEstu($scope, obtenerPerfilEstu, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaFile, salirApp, $element) {

    var Perfil, Mes, Periodo_Estu, input, button, evtHandler, dataImage;

    $scope.data = {};

    Mes = moment().format('MM');

    if (Mes < 07) {
        Periodo_Estu = "Periodo - I";
    } else {
        Periodo_Estu = "Periodo - II";
    }

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {

        obtenerPerfilEstu.datosPerfil().then(function (data) {

            Perfil = data;

            $scope.Cedula = Perfil.cedula;
            $scope.Nombre = Perfil.nombre;
            $scope.Apellido = Perfil.apellido;
            $scope.Rol = Perfil.rol;
            $scope.Facultad = Perfil.facultad;
            $scope.Programa = Perfil.programa;
            $scope.Semestre = Perfil.semestre;
            $scope.Periodo = Periodo_Estu;

        });


        dataImage = localStorage.getItem("imgData");

        if (dataImage === null) {
            $scope.data.ImageURI = "img/profile_icon.png";
        } else {
            $scope.data.ImageURI = dataImage;
        }  

    });   


    $scope.obtenerFoto = function (){
         navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {              
             quality: 100,
             destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
             sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
         });
    };

    function onSuccess(imageURI) {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.src = imageURI;
        localStorage.setItem("imgData", imageURI);        
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    salirApp.salida();

}


obtenerPerfilEstu.$inject = ['$cordovaSQLite', '$ionicHistory'];

function obtenerPerfilEstu($cordovaSQLite, $ionicHistory) {

    return {

        datosPerfil: function () {

            var sqlConsulta, db, perfil, datos, l_perfil, i, fila;

            sqlConsulta = "SELECT Cedula, Nombre, Apellido, Rol, Facultad, Programa, Semestre FROM Estudiante";
            perfil = {};


            if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isIPad()) {
                db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'unicesar.db', location: 'default' });
            } else {
                db = window.openDatabase("unicesar.db", '1.0', 'unicesar', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
            }

            perfil = $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, sqlConsulta, []).then(function (resultado) {

                l_perfil = resultado.rows.length;

                for (i = 0; i < l_perfil; i++) {

                    fila = resultado.rows.item(i);

                    datos = {

                        cedula: fila.Cedula,
                        nombre: fila.Nombre,
                        apellido: fila.Apellido,
                        rol: fila.Rol,
                        facultad: fila.Facultad,
                        programa: fila.Programa,
                        semestre: fila.Semestre

                    };

                }

                return datos;

            }, function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });


            return perfil;

        }

    };

}
```

I use the same code for both views, but the error has never appeared, remember me.

I have tested on multiple devices with different versions of android and two of them with the same version, one works (Moto G4 Plus) and the other appears the error (Samsung J1 2016).

**Versions in which it works**

- 4.2.2
- 5.0.1
- 6.0.1
- 7.0+

**Versions in which it fails**

- 5.1
- 6.0.1

**With error**

[image: con error]

**With out error**

[image: sin error]

Comment: I would suggest you to check if on all android version's the image path is correct. Also have you added some image sanitization to app.config $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|blob|cdvfile):|data:image\//);

Comment: thanks, i try that, but the problem principal is not the image, in that case, is the width content in the screen, can u help me?

Comment: is that way [code](https://pastebin.com/fbur2mZx)

Comment: yes you could give that a try, but i cannot promise 100%. My guess is that because of the image issue the width content is behaving in that way. I have no way of telling unless you share some more js code.

Comment: edit my question, can you check the js code?

Comment: mostrarPerfilEstu.$inject on this are you missing $element ?

Comment: is not necesary, i put this, and show an error